# ST_DWithin makes query slow (> 1000ms)

Tags: performance, postgis

I have a table (natomr) with 200 records which defines different areas. I want to find out what area(s) that contains an arbitrary point. This is my SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM natomr
WHERE ST_DWithin(the_geom4326, 
  ST_geomfromtext('POINT(13.614807 59.684035)', 4326)::geography, 1)
```

This query takes about 1200 ms, which I assume is way too long for such small table.

I have created an index for the_geom4326, like this:

```
CREATE INDEX natomr_the_geom4326_gist
  ON natomr
  USING gist
  (the_geom4326 );
```

I have also run **VACUUM FULL** command, but that did not have any effect.

What should I do to speed up the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell if this is unexpected or not from what you have here...1200MS might be expected.

- Auto vacuum prevents data wrap...shouldn't have a speed effect on a table this small
- Table is almost too small for the index to really be effective.

Some potentials:

st_dwithin has a certain amount of overhead associated with it...it is composed of 3 calls of two other functions that are entirely contrib library files (in C).  So your run time is going to look something like overhead + x seconds per record processed.  Try scaling your data up a bit...try 10 points in a single query.  This will give you a better idea of the overhead associated with st_dwithin.

How big are the polygons in the shape files?  As an interesting test, try defining a 5 point polygon and attempt do the query to find a point in that polygon.  Now define a 2000 point polygon and try the same test.  If your 200 polygons here are 2000 points and larger, 1200MS doesn't sound too unreasonable depending on the power of your machine.

Comment: It turned out to be the ::geography function that slowed it down. When I removed it took 17ms!

Comment: @luttkens so if you cast to geography ? what then? I need to do?